# AppStore language description and "Localization native development region"

Tags: app-store, screenshot, info.plist

an iPhone app, localized in three languages (english, italian and spanish), was submitted to the AppStore with description and screenshots in the three languages.
The result is that in AppStore USA there is an english description, in the AppStore Spain there is a spanish description and in the AppStore Italy there is an italian description, but in all the others AppStore the language description is the italian.

I think the problem is that in the info.plist file, the "Localization native development region" entry is set to Italy, isn't it?
But I don't succeed in explaining another thing: if "Localization native development region" changes from Italy to UK or USA, the language description should change to english, but it should be still wrong for that countries, for example the south american states, which can read a spanish description. Is it possible change this behaviour by associating the appstore with the language more suitable.

**EDIT**

Searching on the web, I realized that the "Localization native development region" info.plist entry hasn't to do with the AppStore description language. It needs to set the app language when there is no available localization. I think that I have to change something in the itunes connect to manage correctly the AppStore description languages, i.e, by setting an english description for almost every available languages.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Apple's reference on CFBundleDevelopmentRegion](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-130430), this key is used as "fallback", when a localized resource is not found. This means it will load Spanish whenever the device is configured for Spanish (Spain, Chile, Argentina, etc). I believe the same happens on Apple Store, since "Spanish" refers to the locale, and not the location.

Comment: But if I access to the spain appstore the language description of the app is spanish, instead in Argentina, chile, etc, appstore the language description of the app is italian

Comment: Was that after changing CFBundleDevelopmentRegion to English? Maybe it's something on the configuration at iTunesConnection.

Comment: No, the primary language on itunes connect is English.