# How to modify Language in Appstore

Tags: app-store

After submitting our app into AppStore in Canada, we found that the Language is "Chinese". In fact, our app is in English at the same time and its description is all in English.

The only place which I think may concern is the "Localization native development region" info.plist entry. But I'm not sure whether changing this entry to en_US will help display the right language in AppStore.

related question: [AppStore language description and "Localization native development region"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979236/appstore-language-description-and-localization-native-development-region)

But I can't catch the answer...

Comment: Try this one instead: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It might help if you say _which_ app store. App stores come like sand on a beach these days...

Comment: @Robuust Thanks, I'll post there.

Comment: @arkascha It's Canada AppStore.